# Auto increment the field based on another field in Laravel model

Tags: php, laravel, model, auto-increment

I have implemented a project in Laravel. 
The following is my database schema.

> A user has many services and a service has many tasks. I have a table
>   "service_tasks" with task_id (auto increment), service_id and
>   task_order fields.

Now when a new task is created, the task order should be auto increment according to the service_id field.

So for example like this.

```
id      service_id      task_order
1       101             1
2       101             2
3       102             1
4       102             2
5       103             1
```

I implemented the following solution.

I count the total task for a service first and add plus one for the order field but When two or more user simultaneously add the task for the same service then the order is not working for a service(the same user is logged in more than one devices and working on the same service).

**Updated**

```
$task = new ServiceTask();
$task->service_id = 139;
$task->task_order = ServiceTask::where('service_id',139)->count()+1;
$task->save();
```

**Note that I can't change the table structure.**

Comment: You could add an `Task::creating` event listener, and set calculate the `service_id` in there compared to where you might do it now

Comment: Can you show some example? I try this one but how can I send service id while creating a task instance?

Comment: In order to make a code example i would need some more context, could you show how/where you are setting it currently?

Comment: This sounds a lot like an [x-y problem](http://xyproblem.info). Why would you need to to this?

Comment: I have updated the question @Quezler

Comment: you should use observables, doesn't task order and service have unique ids???